# How to pass a variable to a IN clause?

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, in-clause

Lets say I have a SP that has a `SELECT` statements as follows,

```
SELECT product_id, product_price FROM product 
WHERE product_type IN ('AA','BB','CC');
```

But data goes to that `IN` clause must be through a single variable that contains the string of values. Something link below

```
SELECT product_id, product_price FROM product 
WHERE product_type IN (input_variables);
```

But its not working that way. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: where is `input_variables` coming from? `php?`

Comment: its actually a direct MYSQL execute from a cron job, so its one of the input parameters of the SP. user enters them depends on what data they want.

Comment: so you mean it is a comma separated value in a single variable?

Comment: It should be. But I can make it the way I want (If I find the correct way to do it :)) , but it'll be a user input.

Comment: well you can't. single variable eventhough it is a comma separated value will be interpreted as single value. Example, you have variable `x = '1','2','3','4'`. when you pass it to `in` like this, `WHERE y IN (x)`, it will be interpreted as `WHERE y IN ('1,2,3,4')` and not `WHERE y IN ('1','2','3','4')`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Pass parameter value like this - `'AA,BB,CC'`. Then, it is enough to use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function -

```
SELECT product_id, product_price
FROM product
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(product_type, param);
```

Comment: this will cause the query to run on all the table without index. Not robust even thought this is a valid answer

Answer (score 3):

create a user-defined function that will convert the comma separated value into table, and by join this two can get the desired result.

[for more](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/comma-delimited-to-table.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

## passing a string using a variable was a problem assume this solution

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spTestListValues`(_list varchar(200))
BEGIN
        SET @LIST=_list; -- assume this a paramter from the stored procedure
    SELECT NULL AS Id,  '' AS Description --insert null value to be used for list box population
    UNION  
    (SELECT id, Description
    FROM test_table
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,@LIST) ORDER BY Description ASC) ;

END
```

## Calling the procedure from other query window

```
call `spTestListValues`('4,5,3'); --no paramter currently for test
```

## output

```
ID Description
NUll 
1   TEST1 
4   TEST2
5   TEST3
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using a prepared statement:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html