# How to use command.Parameters.AddWithValue with value?

Tags: c#, mysql

My code is as below:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs))
{

    string sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE dOCode IN ('" + Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs + "'); ");

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();

                using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Response.Write(reader["dOCode"].ToString() + "<br />");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Output:

```
D410
D420
D430
D440
```

Now I tried use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` in `MySql` query.

I have been trying and cannot find error, the output when use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` is empty, why ?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs))
{

    string sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE dOCode IN (?); ");

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs);

                using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Response.Write(reader["dOCode"].ToString() + "<br />");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit #2**

```
var parameters = new string[Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs.Length];
var paramValue = string.Join(", ", parameters);


string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE dOCode IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(x => "?")));

int index = 0;
foreach (var param in parameters)
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param{index}", param);
   index++;
}
```

**Edit #1**

My new code is as below:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs))
{
   var parameters = new string[Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs.Length]; 

   string sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE dOCode IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters));

        using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
            new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand command =
                new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs.TrimStart('\'').TrimEnd('\'').Length; i++)
                    {
                       parameters[i] = string.Format("param1{0}", i);
                       command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs.TrimStart('\'').TrimEnd('\'')[i]);
                    }                    

                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Response.Write(reader["dOCode"].ToString() + "<br />");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Error :

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.24-log]You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ) at line 1

Comment: [Don't use AddWithValue.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: The problem might be that you insert a list of values in the first approach like `IN ('A', 'B')` whereas when using `AddWithValue` you insert all values into just one parameter which ends in `IN ('A. B')`. Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13116042/642579

Comment: The fact that you are doing this in a Master Page only means you are doing it in the wrong place and has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: I don't know if the ODBC objects will work the same as the SQL ones, but this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377506/pass-array-parameter-in-sqlcommand

Comment: Consider using Dapper instead. https://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-list

Comment: @David
Thank you for help, please see the **Edit #1** in my first question.

Comment: @Markus
Thank you for help, please see the **Edit #1** in my first question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That article is about SqlClient / SQL Server. There's really no reason to avoid `AddWithValue` for MySQL; it doesn't have the `varchar` vs `nvarchar` issue that he talks about and everything gets converted to a string on the wire anyway. (Source: I wrote a MySQL driver: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I don't work with MySql (did some work with it in the past, though) so I'll take your word for it. Still, I think it's better to use `add` even only for readability.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, you can change your query to the following string:

```
SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(dOCode, ?)
```

Then, you need to make sure that your parameter is set in the form `D410, D420, D430, D440`. So you could build it as in your first approach like

```
var paramValue = string.Join(", ", parameters);
```

and add it later on

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", paramValue);
```

Please note that using `FIND_IN_SET` might have a negative impact on performance as it will scan the whole table regardless of index. An alternative would be to insert n parameters into the query and then add each parameter individually, e.g.

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE dOCode IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(x => "?")));
// ...
int index = 0;
foreach(var param in parameters)
{
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"param{index}", param);
  index++;
}
```

This is a viable way if the number of parameters that is to be expected is not too high.

Comment: Thank you, but new error now ERROR [HY001] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.24-log]Memory allocation error

Comment: The parameters are **'D410','D430','D440','D420'**

Comment: My new code in **Edit #2** in my first question, thank you-

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland maybe you can check the following: do you have a `$` in `.AddWithValue($"param{index}", param);`? `param` does not need quotation marks once it is used in a parameter. Does `param` have any quotation marks?

Comment: Not quotation marks in `param` ... The code posted on reply from @Hamamelis working in my case ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this in c#. I hope I was helpful.

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs))
    {
        var paramValue = string.Join(", ", Mpdue.TheObjectPropertyNameNs);

        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM doTable WHERE dOCode IN ({0})", paramValue.ToString());

        ...

        foreach (var param in paramValue)
        {
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", param.ToString());
        }

        ...
   }
```